# Silverstripe blog items and pagination

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe 3.1 site setup and using the `silverstripe-blog` module. I have changed my `BlogHolder.ss` template to display 12 blog items instead of 10 using this code:

```
<% if $BlogEntries(12) %>
   <% loop $BlogEntries(12) %>
      <% include BlogSummary %>
   <% end_loop %>
<% else %>
   <h2><% _t('BlogHolder_ss.NOENTRIES', 'There are no blog entries') %></h2>
<% end_if %>
```

However, the pagination still pages by 10 items.

I looked into the module and can see BlogTree.php sets up the paging with:

```
$list = new PaginatedList($entries, Controller::curr()->request);
$list->setPageLength($limit);
return $list;
```

How can I alter this limit without altering the module code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the admin, and click on the BlogHolder page. Now go to settings and update the field for **Posts per page**

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. In my case, the blog plugin version was so old that this admin setting didn't even exist!